# Android notification is not working properly with AlarmManager

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager, android-notifications, android-alarms

I want to show notifications in my app daily at specified time , The notifications are working fine . When i launch my app for first time no matter what time it is i get a notification and when i click on that notification it takes me to DetailActivity , when i click back button to get to MainActivity the another notification is created. I tried Every thing i could think of but nothing works.

P.S. It is my first time with notifications and AlarmManager.

Here is my code From MainActivity.java

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    rvWord = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    rvWord.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));

    mDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    dictionaryAdapter = new DictionaryAdapter();
    dictionaryAdapter.setCursor(mDBHelper.getDictionaryWord(""));
    rvWord.setAdapter(dictionaryAdapter);

    // Show banner ads
    mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

    showTimedNotification(this); // Shows Notification

    showRatingDialog(); // Shows Rating Dialog

    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

}
private void showTimedNotification(Context context) {

    Calendar updateTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    updateTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
    updateTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 5);
    updateTime.set(Calendar.SECOND,10);

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
            0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager alarms = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarms.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, updateTime.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I used AlarmManager, but could this because you're setting the `triggerAtMillis` parameter to the current date with a time of 08:05:10, and in the cases where this is in the past, it fires the Alarm?

Each time you enter MainActivity `onCreate` the Alarm is scheduled again for the same time, thus re-firing the Alarm?

You could try adding:
`updateTime.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);`
When scheduling the alarm to make it fire at 8AM tomorrow morning.

If you wanted to be thorough, you could check if the current time is before 8AM (between 00:00 and 08:00) and only add the extra day if it is after 8AM, but try this out and see how it goes.

Comment: I want to show the notification daily at 8 a.m , could please tell me how should I do it

Comment: Well you're doing everything right for the notification, but the problem is it's firing a bit early. I'll edit my answer to reflect this :)

Comment: @John updated answer with suggestion for adding 1 day to the trigger time

Comment: I will try your solution and let you know

Comment: Well it worked but instead of 08:05 the alarm fired at 09:08

Comment: @John The only thing I can think of for that much of a difference would be a timezone issue? The `setInexactRepeating` doesn't guarantee that it will fire at exactly the time specified, but it shouldn't be late by 1 hour